# Is Okotowarishimasu for a politer Kotowarimasu a type of form that can be used for other verbs?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Or just a special case for Kotowaru?

For the changing verbs to -ri + shimasu. Is this a standard form?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `お-[V ます-stem]-します` is not just polite. It is used to turn a verb into a humble expression. Being a humble expression, the verb normally refers to something the speaker does to or for the listener, for example:

> - お[受]{う}けします（from [受]{う}けます）
> - お[持]{も}ちします（from [持]{も}ちます）
> - お[送]{おく}りします（from [送]{おく}ります）
> - お[迎]{むか}えします（from [迎]{むか}えます）
> - お[届]{とど}けします（from [届]{とど}けます）
> - お[薦]{すす}めします（from [薦]{すす}めます）

Note that the り in お[断]{ことわ}りします is part of the stem of this particular verb [断]{ことわ}ります.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works for other verbs too, and makes the sentence politer. Some examples are :

座る → お座り

届ける → お届け *

泊まる → お泊まり

しまう → おしまい

見舞う → お見舞い *

釣る → お釣り *

祭る → お祭り *

出掛ける → お出掛け

願う → お願い

巡る → お巡り (In this case the reading changes from meguru to omawari.)

薦める → お薦め (Frequently used by おすすめ or オススメ) *

Most of these make the sentence politer, and the ones with * are frequently used as a noun, as if they are a different word.